# Uri throwing Uber Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, geolocation, uri

I am developing a geo located based app, and I have an option : "Show me the way" that should show the map and how to get there, so far is working with google maps, and also with Waze, the Uber app is showing in the App selector to open the action (Intent) that I'm throwing from the app, but it does not work with the data is receivng, so  What additional data should I send? I was reading the Uber official documentation but it's more for web and URL based calls and I haven't found an example with the "geo" tag Intent that I'm using and works for other apps.

The code I am using to throw the Intent is this:

```
case R.id.menu_ride:
    {
      String uri = "geo: "+newPlace.getLatitude()+","+newPlace.getLongitude();
      startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
      return  true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the right way to do it but this is the way I am using it and it's working on Google Maps, Uber and Waze with no problems:

```
case R.id.menu_ride:
    {
      String uri = "geo: "+newPlace.getLatitude()+","+newPlace.getLongitude() +
                   "?q="+newPlace.getLatitude()+","+newPlace.getLongitude()  ;
          startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
          return  true;
    }
```

Seeems like you had to add the GET parameter "q" for the query.